# Как узнать свой Sudo пароль?

Tags: linux, sudo

коллеги!

Я новичок в работе с линукс подобными системами и только начинаю учиться пользоваться командной строкой.
Для возможности работать в любом месте я решил установить эмулятор терминала на свой старенький Ipad mini 2 под названием NewTerm2.
При первой же попытке обновить все пакеты - `apt update` получаю ошибку:

> E: Не удалось открыть файл блокировки /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
> E: Невозможно заблокировать каталог /var/lib/apt/lists/

В интернете нашел решение обновиться через администратора, то есть через sudo, но при попытке - `sudo apt update` запрашивает пароль, который при установке NweTerm2 я не задавал. Вот теперь и не понимаю какой же должен быть sudo пароль.

```
iPad-Admin:~ mobile% apt update  
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово  
E: Не удалось открыть файл блокировки /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)  
E: Невозможно заблокировать каталог /var/lib/apt/lists/  
%  
iPad-Admin:~ mobile% sudo apt update   
[sudo] password for mobile:
```

Comment: Туда вводится пароль пользователя у которого есть права администратора.

Comment: Если его нет просто ничего не вводим, жмём энтер.

Comment: @ori, разве пароль запрашивается, если его нет?

Comment: Гугл [говорит](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/8yj5ok/tutorial_how_to_change_your_root_password_stay/) `alpine`.